# WebBrowser control external scripting doesn't work

Tags: c#, com, webbrowser-control

This is the HTML, which is stored in a string resource:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>
           (function(){
               window.external.hello()
           })()
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

This is the contents of Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JSIE
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
            webBrowser1.Document.Write(String.Empty);
            webBrowser1.Document.Write(Properties.Resources.DDocument);
            webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new JSCallbacks();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is JSCallbacks.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JSIE
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [ComVisible(true)]

    public class JSCallbacks
    {
        public void hello() {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, it can't access the `hello()` method in the JavaScript `window.external` object, and gives me a script error message box. I have tried using `this` as the `ObjectForScripting`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: For those uninitiated with `ObjectForScripting`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Comment: Okay, this is weird. For some reason the `hello()` function isn't "there" when I call it from a `<script>` tag, yet it is if I call it from an event attribute (`onclick=""`, etc).

Comment: oh, that's likely because your DOM hasn't initialized by the time you call that code. Your code is running before the rest of the DOM is parsed.

Comment: Can you capture a live output of the DOM after your form loads? (sorry, I'm not 100% familiar with this object either, and have never written anything using it. Assuming you can capture the live DOM element after loading)

Comment: You have a weird way to load the document. How about setting the DocumentText property after setting ObjectForScripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it: You have to use the DocumentText property to load HTML *before* the page is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigate as for loading content, but you will need some trick:

remark: I used it with localhost url

```
WebBrowser.Navigate(url);
// wait for ready state after calling Navigate; you can put it into WebBrowser.Navigated as event handler
while (WebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
}

WebBrowser.DocumentText = WebBrowser.DocumentText; // Here is The Trick!

// window.external will work now from WebBrowser content
```